# Send the argument of a custom function as an email

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to send email via script in Google Spreadsheet. I know that the argument in this case cell B4 will be integer.

In my cell is function `=sendEmails(B4)` and my script looks like this.

```
function sendEmails(result) {
  var cell = Number(result);
  Logger.log(cell);
  Logger.log(result);
  MailApp.sendEmail("info@domain.com", "Lab", cell);
  MailApp.sendEmail("info@domain.com", "Lab", result);
}
```

But the problem is that in the logs it shows this and the same arrives by email.

> [15-09-27 20:13:01:449 CEST] NaN
>   [15-09-27 20:13:01:449 CEST] undefined

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Custom functions should return a value to display but the code included in the question doesn't return it (see [Custom Functions in Google Sheets - Apps Scripts Guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)), by the other hand, IMHO, a custom function should not be used to send emails, they only should be used to calculated the value to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rubén pointed out, custom functions cannot be used for this purpose. Sending an email requires authorization, which is not a part of custom function workflow.  Quoting from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

> custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data, specifically the following:

[a list that does not include MailApp]

The same page offers a solution:

> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.